# Why is it that my Deltoid muscle cracks sometimes when I lift my arm?

Tags: exercise, muscle

I have come to situations where I finish exercising, or not even exercising , I lift my right arm, and within the shoulder muscle (Deltoid); the muscle cracks (inside the muscle).

My left shoulder does the same thing, only it doesn't do it that loudly.

**Why does my muscles do this**?

Comment: I've heard "muscle sore", "muscle tear", muscle strain", etc etc etc but "muscle cracks" is a new one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shoulder cracks or clicks are not from the shoulder muscles.

Rather, usually the tendons or a Labral tear are the causes for such noises.

Even if the cracks are not accompanied with pain you should, at the very least, have a competent personal trainer (or even a physical therapist) work with you on your shoulder training.

- I have my clients do their shoulder presses, shoulder flies etc. at a bit of an anterior angle (slightly in front of them) as suggested by **Jeff Cavaliere**, PT. This generally gets rid of the clicking and even discomfort.

If you are feeling discomfort/pain with the cracking you should see your medical care provider about it to rule out any injuries.

Answer (score 1):

### Shoulder *(Synovial Joint)* "Cracking"

---

Until recently experts thought "cracking" had to do with the collapse of air bubbles in the synovial fluid that lubricates joints. ***New evidence suggests the sound is actually caused by precisely the opposite the formation of a gas-filled cavity when the bones in joints stretch apart.***

---

There's actually a showing the process of joint cavitation -- what it looks like when a synovial joint is "cracking".

**[Real-Time Visualization of Joint Cavitation](https://media.wired.com/photos/5909655276f462691f012f26/master/w_482,c_limit/Real-time-MRI-of-joint-cracking.gif)**

> As the bones in the joint separate, negative pressure means gas
>   *(likely nitrogen)* in the synovial fluid gathers together, resulting in the sudden formation of bubbles along with the cracking noise.

---

**Sources**

- http://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0119470
- Image from http://wired.com